# How to modify NEW record in trigger function

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have two simple tables in postgres below:
**models table**:

| id | Model_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | l01 |
| 2 | l06 |

**overrides table:**

| id | value | model_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 26 | 1 |
| 2 | 54 | 2 |

with one to many relationship, where each model can many overrides.

I have setup a NOTIFY and trigger function on override table and I can LISTEN to the channel and get NEW records which new overrides inserted into the override table.

```
create function NotifyOnDataChange()
   returns trigger 
   language plpgsql
  as
$BODY$
DECLARE 
  data JSON;
  notification JSON;
BEGIN
  data = row_to_json(NEW);
  notification = json_build_object(
            'table',TG_TABLE_NAME,
            'action', TG_OP, 
            'data', data);  
            
  PERFORM pg_notify('datachange', notification::TEXT);
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$;

CREATE TRIGGER "OnDataChange"
  AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE 
  ON "public"."overrides"
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE NotifyOnDataChange();
```

I am listening to the notifications in a .NET console application. but I do need to query DB again for model_name knowing the model_id from json object.

My problem is that I rather bring back model_name from postgres instead of model_id but not sure how I can achieve that.So, is there a way to join on Records and replace model_id with its value model_name from models table?

Comment: Sure, just do `SELECT model_name FROM models WHERE id = NEW.model_id` and include that value in your json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query `models` in the trigger function. Note also, that the value of the `new` record is undefined when the trigger is fired on `DELETE`, so you should check this.

```sql
create or replace function NotifyOnDataChange()
   returns trigger 
   language plpgsql
as
$body$
declare 
    data json;
    notification json;
    m_name text;
    rec record;
begin
    rec = case tg_op
        when 'DELETE' then old
        else new end;

    select model_name
    into m_name
    from models 
    where id = rec.id;
    
    data = row_to_json(rec);
    notification = json_build_object(
            'table',TG_TABLE_NAME,
            'action', TG_OP, 
            'data', data, 
            'model_name', m_name);
    perform pg_notify('datachange', notification::text);
    return rec;
end;
$body$;
```

Comment: OP might be looking for `data['model_name'] = m_name;` instead of putting it directly on the `notification`

Comment: Perhaps, I think he can easily handle this modification.

Comment: much obliged klin, got it working